# Optimizing full text search in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, optimization, full-text-search, string-matching

I am using full text search to find certain items in a huge tree structure. Most of the time I am only interested in matching items under a node. But when I use select * from MYTABLE where  match 'XXX', it does a full text search through the whole tree structure.

Is there a way I can specify the rows in MYTABLE that would be used for full text search? (i.e. to match 'XXX'). Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The only queries that work efficiently on FTS tables are `MATCH` searches, and searches for the `rowid`/`docid`.

Therefore, to search for a subtree, you should make the ID of the (root of the) subtree a part of the full text that is being searched.
Please note that most tokenizers throw away interpunctuation characters, so that ID should probably be a sentence where the words specify the path from the root to the subtree.
For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable MATCH 'ID:"root 3 1 4" Text:whatever'
```

You might increase selectivity of the words in the ID if you include the tree level in each word:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable MATCH 'ID:"1x3 2x1 3x4" Text:whatever'
```